# How to get parameter from this url?

Tags: php, url, parameters

normally it is working as expected, but while building my login page it is not working as I want to.

Well url is http://localhost/?page_id=96?msg=INVALID_PASSWORD_MSG

And I am trying to make it work this..but it is not working, I will be happy for every help :)

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) { ?>
<div class="invallidpassword"><cite><?php echo $_GET['msg']; ?></cite></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to use & for multiple params. `?page_id=10&msg=lol`

Comment: lol thanks that may be it :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to correct the question marks. Lets say you have a `query` page which retrieves page content from database. Then
It should be something like following.

http://localhost/query?page_id=96&msg=INVALID_PASSWORD_MSG

The first question mark added after the requested page, and the parameters are separated by &

Comment: If you read carefully and you will understand the answer is more detailed and helps more... @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ

Comment: if you are satisfied with it, that is fine with me.